# restarting timer

Tags: android, timer

I would like the `Timer` to start when I turn `ToggleButton` ON and to cancel when I turn it OFF. It works, but when I try to start it over again after being cancelled I get an error. Where is the problem? Here is the code:

```
final ToggleButton btnLive = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.live);
    btnLive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (btnLive.isChecked()) {

                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(timerTask, 5*1000, 5*1000);

            } else {

                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
                timer = null;

            }
        }
    });
```

EDIT: It works with calling  timer that way:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
                    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            new Something().execute();
                        }
                    };
                    public void run() {
                        handler.post(runnable);
                    }
                }, 5*1000, 5*1000);
```

Can you explain me why first method is not working? Is it range problem?

Comment: @DrGlass try pasting the logcat, if the app has stopped I would assume there is a red entry in the logcat denoting an exception.  That will help point out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this type of code and check.

```
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, 5000, 500);
```